# What determines if item would be stolen or just taken?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I sometimes take half of a shops items while the oher half is considered stealing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36594/why-can-i-sometimes-take-half-of-a-shops-items-while-the-oher-half-is-considered)

When inside house, usually all items say "steal" instead of "take" - make sense, all good.

But sometimes some items are "stealable" while others can be taken without any fear of stealing, and sometimes even in the same cabin/chest some items are red while others are not.

What determines this behavior? Sometimes I did quests for the house owners then most items became eligible to take but sometimes even in empty house, I could still take some items without stealing them.

Comment: Sorry saw the duplicate just after posting..

Comment: Don't worry about it :)

Comment: @badp thanks, I considered to just delete the question - what's your opinion?

Comment: A dupe can always be useful in funneling more people towards a question. Feel free to delete it, or keep it. There's no wrong answer here.