# Why was I allowed to loot the Invarstead inn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I sometimes take half of a shops items while the oher half is considered stealing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36594/why-can-i-sometimes-take-half-of-a-shops-items-while-the-oher-half-is-considered)

Maybe I missed a piece of dialogue that explained this, but when I entered the inn at Ivarstead I was pretty much allowed to take everything that wasn't nailed down.

The only things I wasn't able to take were a few weapons laying in a room, because I'm guessing those belonged to a guest rather than the Inn.

Was there a reason I was allowed to take everything, including the coins from behind the counter? I'm still early in the game, but I don't believe the other inns allowed me to clear them out.

The only related quests I completed was...

> The first Greybeards quest and investigating the ghost in Shroud Hearth Barrow

Is this a type of reward for completing quests?

Comment: I know there's a question for this already... but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @yx. I found it. :P

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that when I was searching.