# Is it safe to pick up items in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I sometimes take half of a shops items while the oher half is considered stealing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36594/why-can-i-sometimes-take-half-of-a-shops-items-while-the-oher-half-is-considered)

There are quite a few items it seems, in the shops I have come across so far, that are available to be picked up with out paying for them that do not have their name in red text showing you are stealing them either. Is there any sort of consequence to collecting these items? Its like almost every Iron item in Alvor's shop. Over half of the items in the alchemy shop in the next town and the like.

I initially thought it was because Alvor was trying to help me out in any way possible, as long as I didnt want steel items. But this seems to be just the standard layout of the shops.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I was actually asking if there were any consequences to taking the items which the other question did not really cover.. but I guess your closing as this being duplicate means there are none since the other question doesn't mention them?

Comment: Correct. As the accepted answer alludes to, there are no consequences. You can pick up their items and sell them back to their owners with no consequences.