# Skyrim: Everything Is Not Permitted

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I sometimes take half of a shops items while the oher half is considered stealing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36594/why-can-i-sometimes-take-half-of-a-shops-items-while-the-oher-half-is-considered)

I've noticed that upon meeting certain people and doing a quest for them to earn their trust, certain things that would be considered stolen are able to be obtained without any trouble and are not labeled as stolen. Though I can't recall the name I remember there was a quest in which you sent a message to a woman about why mining operations were slow and that the shipment would be there soon. After, if you go back to the quest giver's house you can take all the ingots and ore in his house and despite it saying "Steal" at the bottom, he does not care and lets you obtain them without trouble. Are there any other situations like this where you may take an NPC's item with their consent so to say?

Comment: No, actually. First off, this was not a shop. Second off, you can just take a couple of items from shops if you are the thane. I've done it. I would know. Not a duplicate sir.

Comment: @TwistedChaos The question title only mentions shops, but the question body mentions houses too. Is there any information you're looking for that the other question/answer doesn't already cover? I don't think I'm clear on what info you're after.

Comment: It is hard for me to be clear on this since I have had so little experience with it but I guess what I'm looking for is what other NPC's are there, that are known by this websites community, that if a quest is done for them they will let you take something from their house that has the action "Steal" over it and they will not care if they are looking at you. This has only happened in the one mission where the man let me take 17 Iron ingots and 4 iron ore from his house and they still had the "Steal" over them.

Comment: @TwistedChaos The answer, that is given in the other question, is all of them. Everyone has a disposition to you and any items that are within a value range they will let you take depending on what they think of you. Some like you on site, others you need to do quests and such for. This is a global mechanic in Skyrim, not limited to a specific person.

Comment: Well I thank you for the help but I'm going to test a couple theories and try to come back with a more specific type of question. I'm still not being specific enough because I'm not getting the kind answer I'm looking for. I'll get back to you on this.