# How does trustworthiness with NPCs work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In light of [Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer)'s [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36597/46216) to [Why can I sometimes take half of a shops items while the oher half is considered stealing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36594/why-can-i-sometimes-take-half-of-a-shops-items-while-the-oher-half-is-considered), how does one get people to like the player-character? In other words, get their disposition higher (towards the player-character) and get them to allow the player-character to take their stuff?
Edit: While rereading kotekzot's answer, I wondered how (easy it is) to affect a relationship negatively.
Edit 2: Then I realized that I was focusing solely on take vs. steal when I could be asking about what else that trustworthiness (as I'll call it instead of relationship) affects. If it is felt that this edit broadens too much; that what trustworthiness affects deserves its own question, this question can be changed back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only legit way to increase an NPC's disposition toward you is to complete quests for them (or somebody close to them, in a few cases). Not all quests will increase disposition and not all NPCs will have a quest for you.

You can also use `setrelationshiprank player 1` in console to befriended the targeted NPC. [Read more about console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console).